# How To Bypass SSL pinning In SPDY protocol?

Tags: tls, certificates, android, spdy

I have been trying for almost a month to intercept the traffic of an android app the uses SSL pinning. I used Android-SSL-TrustKiller and SSLUnpinning but it did not work.I also decompiled the app and added mitmproxy's certificate to the app's truststore but still no luck.After some investigation I found that the app is using SPDY protocol.I thought that this might be the source of the problem so I searched google about how this protocol perform SSL certificate validation but I could not find anything.

So does SPDY protocol uses a different mechanism for SSL pinning? if not then what is preventing the app from trusting the proxy after I have added the proxy's certificate to the app's truststore?

Answer (score 2):

SPDY work different from HTTP, the proxy must support it.
I guess [this](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/277) is your problem. mitmproxy does not support SPDY.

You need to look for proxy that support SPDY, somethink like [this one](https://github.com/igrigorik/node-spdyproxy). If you can make the phone\app trust your certificate, it should work.